# Cannot find sun.tools.java.* while compiling openjdk-7

Tags: jvm, java

I am trying to compile openjdk-7 source code on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
export LANG=C ALT_BOOTDIR=/usr
make all
```

I saw some errors like:

```
symbol: class ClassNotFound
location: class CompoundType
../../../../src/share/classes/sun/rmi/rmic/iiop/CompoundType.java:1299: error: cannot find symbol
```

These missing classes are all in the package named `sun.tools.java`. I suspect these are some nonstandard libs required by the jdk build process. However I cannot find relevant information in online build tutorials. So what are these missing classes and how I can fix them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications need the `tools.jar` from the JDK which has these packages.  This is often used for runtime compilation of generated code. Add this to the class path from your JDK.

Note: these are not package you would normally pass via RMI however. I would have a look at the classes to see why it would need to do this.

Comment: tools.jar is under /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle on my machine. So ALT_BOOTDIR should be set to that path. java under /usr/bin is just soft link.